While images appear in debug and release mode in my Xamarin android application, images do not appear when published in aab format.aab
I have a Xamarin android project. I tested it in debug and release mode, the images appear, the application works fine. But when I publish it to Google Play (I create and publish the package in .aab format), none of the images, not even the icons in the tabbar menu, appear. What am I doing wrong?


Pictures are in the Content within the ClinicApp Project. The project for which I created the package is the ClinicApp.Android project. However, as I said, when I run the ClinicApp.Android project, the images appear in both debug/release modes. It doesn't show up when I publish it to Google Play
How can I make image icons appear?
